# Is there a way to get rid local 'worktree' folders which point towards non-existent branches on remote

Tags: git, git-worktree

I'm a big fan of `git worktree` command. My project directory contains a number of folders which points to branches which I'm working on at the moment.

```bash
.../project directory                
├── bugfix             
│   ├── IBD-15         
│   ├── IBD-17         
│   ├── IBD-18         
│   ├── IBD-21         
│   ├── IBD-22         
│   └── IBD-23  
...       
├── main             
└── story              
    ├── logs           
    └── IBD-7      
                       
X directories
```

Over a time I close a **feature** via merge request using CI instruments (CI automatically deletes a remote branch).
But **feature branch** keeps alive in the project folder and I need periodically watch through the list of closed features and manually remove the folders which points to non-existent branches on remote:

```bash
$ rm -rf bugfix/IBD-15
$ rm -rf bugfix/IBD-23
...
$ git worktree prune
```

So is there a way to get rid **worktree folders** for **branches** which don't exist anymore on **remote** (of course if the 'worktree' folder doesn't contain not pushed commits or untracked local changes) ?

Comment: Did you forget to insert a verb in the title? "which [?] towards"

Comment: Use `git fetch --prune` to update your remote-tracking names; observe which names are now gone (e.g., `origin/bugfix/xxx`); and use that to run `git worktree rm` after making sure that this is OK.

Comment: `n` worktrees for `n` feature/issue branches sounds like `n` too many.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested what happens after a `git fetch --prune` regarding existing worktree.

A `git branch -avv` would show:

```
+ ee                    60f5e46 (C:/Users/vonc/git/tests/b2/ee) [origin/ee: gone] Move...
```

That means you can do something like:

```
git branch -avv|grep ": gone"|cut -f 2 -d '('|cut -f 1 -d ')'|xargs git worktree remove
```

And all your obsolete worktrees would be gone. In one line.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote for weekends an [interactive bash](https://github.com/iharkatkavets/terminal-snippets/blob/master/bin/worktree-cleanup.sh) script which walk through all worktree folders and ask user for removing the folder. The script checks if upstream branch exists on remote or unpunished commits exist in worktree folder. You need to run the script from any worktree folder and it will do it's job.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# filename: worktree-cleanup
#
# get rid 'worktree' folders which branches doesn't exists 
# This script automatically walks through all wortree folders
# and ask for removing them
#
CUR_DIR=$(pwd)

function pushd {
  command pushd "$@" > /dev/null
}

function popd {
  command popd "$@" > /dev/null
}

function locate_git_tool {                         
  for path in ${PATH//:/ }; do                     
    [ -x "$path/git" ] && echo "$path/git" && break
  done                                             
  echo ""                                          
} # end of function locate_git_tool                

function git_fetch {
  $GIT_TOOL fetch --all
}

function contains_untracked_changes {
  local dir=$1
  pushd "$dir"
  local status="$($GIT_TOOL status --short)"
  popd
  echo "$status"
} # end of function contains_untracked_changes

function is_git_dir {
  local dir="$1"
  pushd "$dir"
  [ -d "$dir" ] && [ -d "$dir/.git" -o -e "$dir/.git" ] 
  popd
} #end of function is_git_dir

function is_dir_exist {
  [ -e "$@" -a -d "$@" ]
} # end of function is_dir_exist

function is_current_dir {
  [ "$CUR_DIR" == "$@" ]
}

function choose {
  local default="$1"
  local prompt="$2"
  local choice_yes="$3"
  local choice_no="$4"
  local answer

  read -p "$prompt" answer
  [ -z "$answer" ] && answer="$default"

  case "$answer" in
    [yY1] ) eval "$choice_yes"
      ;;
    [nN0] ) eval "$choice_no"
      ;;
    *     ) printf "%b" "Unexpected answer '$answer'!" >&2 ;;
  esac
} # end of function choose

function contains_unpushed_commits {
  pushd "$@"
  local output=$(git log @{u}.. -p)
  popd
  echo "$output"
}

function is_upstream_branch_exists {
  local path="$1"
  local branch="$2"
  pushd "$path"
  local output=$(git ls-remote --heads --quiet | grep 'branch')
  popd
  echo "$output"
}

function cleanup_worktree_folder {
  local path="$1"

  choose "y" \
    "Remove $path? (y or n)" \
    "$GIT_TOOL worktree remove --force \"$path\"" \
    ":"
}

function check_and_cleanup_forlder {
  local path="$1"
  local branch="$2"

  if [ ! -z "$(contains_untracked_changes $path)" ] ; then
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "Warning: $path contains changes" "$(contains_untracked_changes $path)"
    cleanup_worktree_folder "$path"
  elif [ -z "$(is_upstream_branch_exists $path $branch)" ] ; then
    printf "%s\n" "Warning: $path doesn't have upstream branch"
    cleanup_worktree_folder "$path"
  elif [ ! -z "$(contains_unpushed_commits $path)" ] ; then 
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "Warning: $path" "$(contains_unpushed_commits $path)"
  else 
    cleanup_worktree_folder "$path"
  fi
}

GIT_TOOL=$(locate_git_tool)
[ -x "${GIT_TOOL}" ] || { printf "%b" "Fatal: 'git' tool not found.\n" ; exit 1 ; }
[ -d "$CUR_DIR/.git" -o -e "$CUR_DIR/.git" ] || { printf "%b" "Fatal: not a git repository.\n" ; exit 1 ; }

git_fetch

IFS=$'\n'       
for line in $($GIT_TOOL worktree list) ; do
  path=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
  branch=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
  branch="${branch%]}"
  branch="${branch#[}"
  if ! $(is_dir_exist "$path") ; then 
    echo "$path not exists"
  elif $(is_current_dir "$path") ; then
    :
  elif ! $(is_git_dir "$path") ; then 
    printf "%b" "Warning: not a git repository. Skip.\n" 
  else 
    check_and_cleanup_forlder "$path" "$branch"
  fi
done
unset IFS
```

You can find the script [here](https://github.com/iharkatkavets/terminal-snippets/blob/master/bin/worktree-cleanup.sh)

Comment: Looks good, more detailed than my answer. Upvoted.